# Setting up NIS/NFS on Mac OS 10.6

Tags: linux, mac, user-accounts, nfs

We have an Ubuntu NIS/NFS server at work and we recently got a few new iMacs. Is there a way to set them up so they can use the linux user accounts and mount the shared nfs files? Are there any guides on how to do this? I've been googling with no success.

I tried getting NFS to work by connecting to the server via the Disk Utility but after I run 'sudo automount' from the command line and ls the directory I tried to mount it to (Volumes/nfs) it gives a permissions error.

If there isn't a way to do this, anyone know of any not to complicated ways to share user accounts and files between mac and linux computers (and even hypothetically a windows computer one day?)

I know its kind a of huge question, but I'll greatly appreciate any advice on the topic. Thanks!

Comment: I've managed to get LDAP working, but not NIS.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about the NFS mounts (AIUI OS X uses a rather unique format for them, so will probably not understand what you have in your NIS domain), but at least in principal, NIS should be easy to set up: run Directory Utility (in /System/Library/CoreServices on v10.6, /Applications/Utilities on earlier versions), select the Services tab, click the padlock and authenticate as a local admin, then double-click the "BSD Flat File and NIS" plugin, enter your domain info and check the "Use NIS domain for authentication" option.

Comment: Gordon,  this solution worked for me (Mac OS 10.6) with one catch.  After a reboot, an administrator on the Mac must login before anyone can authenticate with their NIS account.  The admin doesn't need to stay logged in, once they login, they can logout or switch users. Than anyone with a NIS account can login.  Any thoughts on what I could do to eliminate this catch?